# Dwarf Fortress tagging

Tags: discussion, dwarf-fortress

In Dwarf Fortress, the main dwarf and adventure modes are quite different. There's one dwarf-fortress tag and one dwarf-fortress-adventure tag. [My question about adventure mode](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52115/how-to-drink-in-a-cold-environment) was retagged, though. Why?

Comment: [This one](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52121/how-to-find-the-location-of-my-target-in-dwarf-fortress/52174#52174) was also retagged.

Comment: @Wipqozn: Can't use chat either without registering. I'll stick to posting real questions and let you guys handle the metaing and other administration, then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should always tag a question with it's game, which in this case is [dwarf-fortress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress). I've re-added the [dwarf-fortress-adventure](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dwarf-fortress-adventure) to your original question as well, since I don't think it should have been removed.